# Typescript + Require.js: extending prototype of String and importing that module

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I am using typescript in AMD mode (using requirejs).

Let's say I want to add a function to String, at the moment I do:

*Extensions/String.ts*

```
interface String {
    startsWith(str: string): boolean;
}

define(() => {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function (str)
    {
        return (this.match("^" + str) == str);
    };
});
```

This works and generate the right .js file and I am able to use in non-typescript requirejs modules.

**How do I "import" this requirejs module in a typescript class?**

In the file of the class that wants to use the new functions, this doesn't work:

*types/SampleClass.ts*

```
import ExtensionsString = require("Extensions/String");
```

I get this error:

> "unable to resolve external module '"Extensions/String"'

How can I make typescript add "Extensions/String" to the list of dependencies

*types/SampleClass.js*

```
define("SampleClass", ["Extensions/String"], function(/* no need to have parameter */){

...

});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ``declare module "Extensions/String" { ... }``

Comment: Your own answer will work but your String.ts is a hybrid between an internal (TS) and external (AMD) module. Which one would you like String.ts to be?

Comment: How would it look like if I use an internal module (non hybrid)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I just need to add the following line in the SampleClass.ts file instead of using import:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="Extensions/String" />
```